# How to make StackSwitcher tabs closeable Gtk/Vala

Tags: gtk, vala

I am trying to make a Stack and StackSwitcher whose pages associated tabs can be added and deleted dynamically. To delete the associated widget in the stack and the tab in the StackSwitcher, I want to have a small delete button in the tab. I have found an example similar to this in the [gtk3-widget-factory](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/tree/master/demos/widget-factory), screenshot shown below.

[image: Dynamic pages in Gtk Notebook]

However, this uses a Notebook and I would like to be able to use the Stack/StackSwitcher setup instead of a Notebook (I don't like how the Notebook creates a background to its pages). I can't figure out how to change the widget that is displayed in the StackSwitcher for each page in the Stack. My intuition is that I should just be able to replace the Label in the StackSwitcher with a Box that has been packed with a Label and Button that has a callback that goes and removes the page and the tab. But I am not able to do this with how I am currently creating the pages of the Stack, which is by calling stack.add_titled(). The StackSwitcher that has been assigned to that stack just automatically picks up the labels with no way of editing them that I have found.

Is there a way to do this for a Stack and StackSwitcher? If not, I would also appreciate some advice for doing it with a Notebook as I have not even been able to recreate what I saw in the widget factory (above). This is the code that I have attempting to recreate it:

```
void main (string[] args) {
    Gtk.init (ref args);

    var window = new Window ();
    window.title = "Example Program";
    window.border_width = 10;
    window.window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER;
    window.set_default_size (350, 70);
    window.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);


    Notebook note = new Notebook();

    Box tabBox = new Box(Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 0);
    Label tabLabel = new Label("Closable Tab");
    Button closeButton = new Button.from_icon_name("window-close-symbolic", IconSize.BUTTON);
    tabBox.pack_start(tabLabel, false, false, 0);
    tabBox.pack_start(closeButton, false, false, 0);    
    
    Label displayLabel = new Label("this page should be closeable");
    note.append_page(displayLabel, tabBox);

    window.add(note);
    window.show_all();

    Gtk.main ();
}
```

which just creates an empty Notebook tab like this:

[image]

and I don't get any error messages about creating that tab failing so I don't know what to do. Any help is appreciated.